# In wso2 BPS for BPMN resttask error handling

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

In wso2 BPS it has provided soap and rest task for rest and soap call but how to handle the error if any error occurs.

In this article [(article link)](https://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/04/article-how-to-model-bpmn-business-processes-with-wso2-business-process-server/) they have provided **RestInvokeError** as the error code. Can we use **RestInvokeError** as error code for error hanling and how to handle soaptask error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For catching rest task error the error code defined in WSO2 EI in bps profile is **REST_CLIENT_INVOKE_ERROR**